# XAML MarkupCompilePass2 fails on a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to build my WPF project I get the folowing error:
`Samotorcan.Client.WPF.Windows8\Views\MainWindow.xaml(1,17): error MC3074: The tag 'Window' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Samotorcan.Client.WPF.Windows8.Controls'. Line 1 Position 17.`
The problem only occurs when I try to use linq. If I have a line like this `new List<object>().ToArray<object>();` somewhere in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`file I get the above error and if I change it to `new List<object>().ToArray();` the error disappears and the project builds successfully.
I also checked the build log and it contains the same error at task MarkupCompilePass2.
I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012.
EDIT
After playing with it a bit I managed to find out that it's not specificly related to linq an random changes like removing an unused file from a project or just removing parts of code like a simple string creating `string s = new String();` fixes the error.
At one point a simple change in a constructor from this

```
public LoggedEventArgs(string message)
{
    Message = message;
}
```

to this

```
public LoggedEventArgs(string message)
{
    // Message = message;
}
```

fixed the error.

Comment: Can you post relevant code here?

Comment: Seems like a build error. How about you close your solution and clear bin folder. Then start your solution again and execute build process few times just to make sure all your assemblies get created. You seem to have few projects. :) Try it out. Might work. Dont forget to clear everything first.

Comment: Deleted all the bin and obj files from all the projects in the solution and after a full rebuild I get the same error.

Comment: Build few more times and not just once. You are saying that whenever you add a statement no matter what kind of type it might be, the building works without errors. That is a building problem and not an error happening when list is being casted to array.

Comment: Build it quite a few times and the error is the same. The error is appearing really random and sometimes adding a statement gets rid of it and sometimes removing other statments works or even removing unused classes sometimes works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a workaround for the above error by moving all my controls from the project into a separate project just for controls.

Now there are no random errors on build because as it looks like it can always find the `window` and other controls that are now in a separate assembly.